# How to convert Joda LocalDate to String in Java?

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I got the answer:
It's very simple.

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
String formattedDate = jodeLocalDateObj.toString( fmt );
```

Comment: Please, don't edit your question when you get the correct answer. The answer is visible for everyone to see here, anyway. Also: if the answer is good (enough) for you, tag it as "the" answer (use the wedge symbol next to the answer you consider the correct one) in order for the poster to get the credit he/she should get for it.

Answer (score 96):

LocalDate's `toString` can take a format string directly, so you can skip creating the DateTimeFormatter:

```
String formattedDate = myLocalDate.toString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#toString-java.lang.String-

Comment: Does toString(string_format) create it's own DateTimeFormatter instance each time you call it?  If so then methods that do a bunch of conversions would be a lot more efficient if they created their own instance and reused with by calling the formatter's print() method.

Comment: @Rick Interestingly, internally Joda (2.3 at least) manages a thread safe pattern cache. It creates its own DateTimeFormatter instance the very first time only and reuses it on each next calls.

Comment: Additionally, I wouldn't spend any of my time worrying about the performance of formatting a date unless I was doing it at least thousands of times. Bigger fish to fry.

Answer (score 42):

While the answer you've found will work, I prefer to look at it the other way round, in terms of which object is "active" (in terms of formatting) and which is just providing data:

```
LocalDate localDate = new LocalDate(2010, 9, 14);
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
String formattedDate = formatter.print(localDate);
```

Comment: I can't find where DateTimeFormat is? can you please give the import statements too

Comment: @samthebest: Did you look in the [Javadoc](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/index.html)? Just a Google search for "joda DateTimeFormat" finds it - but if not, http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html

Comment: Oops, I misread the question, I thought this was for java 8 time, not joda.

Answer (score 6):

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
String formattedDate = jodeLocalDateObj.toString( fmt );
```