# How to convert java.util.Date objects into Calendar objects?

Tags: java, date, calendar

I'm using the [PrettyTime](http://ocpsoft.org/prettytime/) java library for a variety of date/time processing in my java app, such as converting MySQL format dates/datetime strings into java dates, or the vice versa.

However, I see that `date.getYear(), date.getMonth()`, etc, are all deprecated, and it says to use Calendar instead.  But PrettyTime only returns its results as Date objects, and I see no way to convert the Date objects into calendar objects.

In the documentation for [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), the only mention I see of `Date` is the method [setTime(Date date)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTime%28java.util.Date%29), but the method name is ambigious, and the documentation is not clear on what calling this method would actually do. Obviously I can't just do `calendar.set( date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), ..)` etc, as those methods of `Date` are deprecated.

So how can I convert a given Date object to Calendar?

Comment: `Calendar calendar = ...; calendar.setTime(someDateObject);` as simple as that

Comment: Or get time in millis.

Comment: You guys apparently type a little faster than I do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
```

You can get the calendar in different locales as well if you want.

You could also do

```
cal.setTimeInMillis(date.getTime());
```

Comment: Thanks, I wish the `setTime` method wasn't named so ambigiously or had a clearer documentation, so I won't have had to ask this.

Comment: As a general recommendation, if you can, try using Joda time. It's much cleaner than the Java standard time.

Comment: @ClickUpvote I would recommend using [joda time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library instead or wait to Java 8 where the Date API is redesigned.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Does it allow creating Date / Calendar objects from a given string, such as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`? That's my main requirement as I need to convert MySQL date/datetime strings into Java date/calendar, or vice versa.

Comment: @ClickUpvote yes, it does.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Could you point me to the method for it? I don't see it at a quick glance through the documentation.

Comment: @ClickUpvote use a SEO. The first result of my search gave me this link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6252678/1065197

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It doesn't seem possible to covert a given `DateTime` to a string in a given format, though.

Comment: @ClickUpvote check here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3709083/1065197.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza That's for a `LocalDateTime`, whereas the `DateTimeFormatter.parse()` returns just a `DateTime`..

Comment: @ClickUpvote `DateTimeFormatter.print` is overloaded to support `ReadableInstant` (like `DateTime`) and `ReadablePartial` (like `LocalDate`). I would heavily recommend to start practicing and see the results for yourself instead of just searching *how can I foo the bar using Joda for an specific case that I won't test*.