# Display dates in multiple fragments

Tags: java, android, date, fragment

I'm having trouble trying to think of a way to display dates in fragments. What I need to do is display today's date at the top of a fragment and then when the user slides or presses a button the a fragment will replace the previous one and display tomorrows date and then the next fragment will display the date after tomorrow and so on.

Comment: I understand how to get tomorrows date using GregorianCalendar but how do I get the day after tomorrows date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what the problem is, but you can get tomorrows date or any date relative to the current time like this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, numberOfDaysToAdd);
Date date = calendar.getTime();
```

Answer (score 2):

## Joda-Time

You can use the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library in Android.

If you only want date, without any time or time zone, use the [LocalDate](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) class.

### Example code

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate tomorrow = today.plusDays( 1 );
LocalDate dayAfterTomorrow = tomorrow.plusDays( 1 ); // or today.plusDays( 2 );
```

### Formatting

To format a LocalDate as a String, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15208893/642706).

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Fragment` that contains the current date and a `Bundle` extra that contains an offset.

```
public class DateFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String DAY_OF_YEAR = "datefragment.DAY_OF_YEAR";

    /**
     * Empty constructor as per the {@link Fragment} docs
     */
    public DateFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * @param offset The number of days to off the {@link Calendar}
     * @return A new instance of <code>DateFragment</code>
     */
    public static DateFragment newInstance(int offset) {
        final Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DAY_OF_YEAR, offset);
        final DateFragment fragment = new DateFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, getArguments().getInt(DAY_OF_YEAR, 1));

        final TextView text = new TextView(getActivity());
        text.setText(df.format(c.getTime()));
        return text;
    }

}
```

**In your `Activity`**

```
    // Your custom PagerAdapter
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    for (int i = 0; i < 365; i++) {
        adapter.buildData(DateFragment.newInstance(i));
    }
    // Bind the data to the ViewPager
    final ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(adapter.getCount());
```

**Results**

This will give you something like "23-Mar-2014" until whenever you chose, in this case a year from now.